# duapp.com trying to hijack SO's seach rankings

Tags: discussion

I know this has happened a lot in the past but I was just snookered into clicking a link for duapp.com after searching google.

stackoverflow.duapp.com/questions/23268645/how-to-read-xml-with-ruby

Like 'real' SO search results, "stackoverflow" comes first in the line so it was easy to make that mistake (I expect intentionally so).

To add to confusion duapp.com after a series of redirects you're directed to page where you can share a 404 error page on social media. duapp.com is hosted by Baidu, but I won't get on my soapbox about that.

Is there anything we can do to remove these useless results from Google search? Is there somewhere else I should report this?

Comment: What is "seach rankings"?

Comment: Use the "contact us" button on the bottom of the page and report it there.